# Webpack shows parent scope as undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

EDIT: I have just gone through the process of switching back to browserify and am having the same problem. So no longer a webpack problem. Still need help though

I am in the process of switching from broswerify to webpack. I have created an abstraction for my ajax calls. In that file I have some private variables that I use to set URL and timeout etc. For some reason it shows these variables (and the entire 'closure') as undefined, leading to some weird bugs. This code was working perfectly fine with browserify.

This is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
 devtool: 'source-map',
 entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'client', 'index.js'),
 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
  publicPath: 'localhost:3002',
  filename: 'bundle.js',
 },
 module: {
  loaders: [
   {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
   },
   {
    test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
   },
  ],
 },
 plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   __API_URL__: JSON.stringify('http://localhost:3002/api'),
  }),
 ],
};
```

This is my api wrapper `api.js`

```js
import request from 'superagent';

import store from './store';
import { system, account } from '../core/actions';

const API_URL = __API_URL__;
const TIMEOUT = 10000;
const _pendingRequests = {};

function getJwt() {
 /**
  * This retrieves the JSON Web Token from local or session storage
  * We simply try both so that we don't have to subscribe to the store
  * and make sure some flag is constantly updated. The reducer that handles
  * the successful login will place the token in the proper place.
  */
 let token = localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN');
 if (token) {
  return 'Bearer ' + token;
 }

 token = sessionStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN');
 if (token) {
  return 'Bearer ' + token;
 }

 return null;
}

function addRequest(key, pendingRequest) {
 _pendingRequests[key] = pendingRequest;
}

function abortPendingRequests(key) {
 if (_pendingRequests.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  _pendingRequests[key]._callback = () => {
  };
  _pendingRequests[key].abort();
  _pendingRequests[key] = null;
 }
}

function digest(resolve, reject) {
 return function consume(err, res) {
  if (err && err.timeout === TIMEOUT) {
   return store.dispatch(system.apiTimeout());

  } else if (res.status === 401) {
   return store.dispatch(account.logout());
  } else if (!res.ok) {
   return reject(res);
  } else {
   if (err) {
    return reject(err);
   } else {
    return resolve(res.body);
   }
  }
 };
}

export function get(actionType, resource) {
 // abortPendingRequests(actionType);
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const jwt = getJwt();

  const url = `${API_URL}${resource}`;

  const requested = request
   .get(url)
   .timeout(TIMEOUT);

  if (jwt) {
   requested.set('Authorization', jwt);
  }

  // addRequest(actionType, requested);

  requested.end(digest(resolve, reject));
 });
}

export function post(actionType, resource, data) {
 // abortPendingRequests(actionType);
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const jwt = getJwt();

  const url = `${API_URL}${resource}`;

  const requested = request
   .post(url)
   .timeout(TIMEOUT);

  if (jwt) {
   requested.set('Authorization', jwt);
  }

  if (data) {
   requested.send(data);
  }

  // addRequest(actionType, requested);

  requested.end(digest(resolve, reject));
 });
}

export function put(actionType, resource, data) {
 // abortPendingRequests(actionType);
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const jwt = getJwt();

  const url = `${API_URL}${resource}`;

  const requested = request
   .put(url)
   .timeout(TIMEOUT);

  if (jwt) {
   requested.set('Authorization', jwt);
  }

  if (data) {
   requested.send(data);
  }

  requested.end(digest(resolve, reject));
 });
}

export function del(actionType, resource) {
 // abortPendingRequests(actionType);
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const jwt = getJwt();

  const url = `${API_URL}${resource}`;

  const requested = request
   .del(url)
   .timeout(TIMEOUT);

  if (jwt) {
   requested.set('Authorization', jwt);
  }

  // addRequest(actionType, requested);

  requested.end(digest(resolve, reject));
 });
}
```

There are some weird comments that are the result of trying to debug the problem. But basically, if I set a breakpoint at `const _pendingRequests = {};` it shows `API_URL` and `TIMEOUT` as being set properly. But if I set a breakpoint at `const url =`${API_URL}${resource}`;` in `export function get` it shows them as undefined as I will show with screenshots.

[image: Parent scope]

[image: Child Scope]

One thing I am just noticing is that it is breaking on the child scope prior to breaking on the parent scope. I am guessing that has something to do with it, but I am not sure how to change this behavior. I work in node so I have written this like I would write it for the server.

This is the file where I am importing `api.js`

```js
import * as api from '../../core/api';
import { endpoints } from '../../constants';

export const FETCH_LOOKUPS = 'FETCH_LOOKUPS';
export const FETCH_LOOKUPS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_LOOKUPS_SUCCESS';

export function fetchLookupsSuccess(lookups) {
 return {
  type: FETCH_LOOKUPS_SUCCESS,
  lookups,
 };
}

export function asyncFetchLookups() {
 return dispatch => {
  return api.get(FETCH_LOOKUPS, endpoints.LOOKUP)
   .then(lookups => dispatch(fetchLookupsSuccess(lookups)));
 };
}

export const FETCH_LANG = 'FETCH_LANG';
export const FETCH_LANG_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_LANG_SUCCESS';

export function fetchLangSuccess(language) {
 return {
  type: FETCH_LANG_SUCCESS,
  language,
 };
}

export function asyncFetchLang() {
 return dispatch => {
  return api.get(FETCH_LANG, endpoints.LANGUAGE)
   .then(language => dispatch(fetchLangSuccess(language)));
 };
}
```

Started digging into the transpiled code and found this

```js
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

 'use strict';
 
 Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
 });
 exports.TIMEOUT = exports.API_URL = undefined;
 exports.get = get;
 exports.post = post;
 exports.put = put;
 exports.del = del;
 
 var _superagent = __webpack_require__(427);
 
 var _superagent2 = _interopRequireDefault(_superagent);
 
 var _store = __webpack_require__(430);
 
 var _store2 = _interopRequireDefault(_store);
 
 var _actions = __webpack_require__(444);
 
 function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
 
 var API_URL = exports.API_URL = ("http://localhost:3002/api"); /**
                                               * This file serves as a wrapper for any ajax requests that need to be made
                                               * - contains a generic call for PUT, POST, GET and DELETE request
                                               * - always attempts to append a JSON Web Token if present
                                               * - keeps track of all pending requests and aborts identical requests
                                               */
 
 var TIMEOUT = exports.TIMEOUT = 10000;
```

As you can see it initially sets TIMEOUT and API_URL as undefined. It then exports `get`, `post` etc and then sets TIMEOUT and API_URL but that is after the exported `get` is already being accessed. Not sure why it sets them to undefined or how to fix this behavior.

Comment: use `var` instead of `const` to declare both `API_URL` & `TIMEOUT`, the transpiler might try to mimic the tdz (temporal dead zone) where it clearly shouldn't (that's all I can say from this code fragment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the function being called prior the javascript finishing parsing I guess. (Still not sure why) The workaround I found was to attach my initialization function to the window object and call it in an IIFE at the body of my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

According to how you require (probably import) the `get` function babel may transpile first the `get` function and hand it over to node's require which then evals it.

You then don't have `API_URL` transpiled yet. This looks like an edge case.

Instead of using the ES6 `export`, just for this file, use `module.exports` and use node's `require` to import it to dismiss that kind of bug.

If this works, try `import`ing instead of `require`ing (and the way around `export`ing instead of using `module.exports`) to narrow the bug.

*Note*: This is more a hint/workaround than a solution. You may provide the file from where you make the require, this might be useful for other people to answer you.

Comment: I have added the actions file where it is required, in case that is helpful. I also quickly tried switching from es6 export to node's require/module.exports. That seemed to make it worse haha. I might try encapsulating the entire file in a factory pattern to see if that helps. I don't like the idea because I want to maintain `api.js` as a singleton and it introduces what I'd consider unnecessary complexity but I'll let you know where I get with that.

Comment: Try `export const API_URL` (I know it breaks encapsulation). Next step is to take a look at the transpiled version to find the bug ...

Comment: I tried `export const API_URL` and `export const TIMEOUT` just to make sure it wasn't a problem with `DefinePlugin` They show up as exports now but still as undefined.

Comment: Last hint: try `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { ...` instead of the fat arrow syntax (which messes internally with the scope - shouldn't cause this kind of bug though)

Comment: No luck. Based on what I see in devtools it is in the correct scope. It is just that certain variables are undefined. I added some transpiled code above.